# Razor Pages and Checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm learning ASP.Net Core Razor Pages and I'm working through various CRUD related exercises from the Microsoft website.

I am trying to expand on these exercises by adding new features and was hoping on getting some guidance in relation to binding/saving/reading checkboxes.

As an example I have a basic person details form, as well as capturing their details and I would like to display a list of checkboxes containing interests that the user can select (i.e. Fishing, cycling, football etc).

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Interest> Interests { get; set; }
}

public class Interest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I can work out using Razor syntax how to loop through my Interest model to pull the values from the database and create the checkboxes with the appropriate Id's and text(Name) on the page but I am unsure what the best way is to save this to the database and also read this information back and to re-populate the correct checkboxes if the user wanted edit the original selection and re-save.

I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: If Interests is an "Information" table (I mean you have pre-defined data and want, for example assign Person X to Interest.Id=1, etc): you need to change your model and create a PersonInterest table in which you will associate Person X with Interest Y. After that you could follow @FeiHan's answer

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox in terms of HTML has 2 states. Checked and Unchecked.

This would translate to a relational database `bit` data type. It can represent either 1 for checked, 0 for unchecked, or NULL for indeterminate.

Indeterminate state (user neither checked or unchecked the box) cannot be represented by HTML by itself. So I would advise to create the record with a default value of 0 (unchecked) and not allow NULL if the bit column is meant to represent a checkbox state in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

> I am unsure what the best way is to save this to the database and also read this information back and to re-populate the correct checkboxes if the user wanted edit the original selection and re-save.

You can refer to the following example to use another property such `SelectedInterestsId` in your page model class for holding the selected Id of interests, like below.

*In page*

```
<form method="post">
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Id
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="PersonAndInterests.Id" />
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Name
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="PersonAndInterests.Name" />
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Address
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="PersonAndInterests.Address" />
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Interests
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @foreach (var item in Model.PersonAndInterests.Interests)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedInterestsId" value="@item.Id" /> @item.Name<br />
            }
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
</form>
```

*In page model class*

```
[BindProperty]
public Person PersonAndInterests { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public List<int> SelectedInterestsId { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    //code logic here
    //...
}

public IActionResult OnPost()
{

    var person_and_interests = this.PersonAndInterests;

    var interests_Id = this.SelectedInterestsId;

    //code logic here
    //...

    //can query interests from db based on SelectedInterestsId
    //then update PersonAndInterests.Interests based on above retrieved interests

    //...


    return Page();
}
```

Test Result

[image]